# Can you specify output length of an encrypted string using AES?

Tags: encryption, aes, rijndael

I am running into an issue with encryption and I am looking for some guidance.

I am using AES encryption (Rijndael) to encrypt and decrypt user passwords, security question answers, and PIN numbers. These encrypted values are then put into a database where the fields are defined as bin(16), bin(32), and bin(64). Originally I was using custom padding to ensure then length of the data, but for security reasons I am moving to PKCS7 padding. Unfortunately, this change has made the length of the encrypted string unpredictable, at least for the password and the security question answers. For example, valid passwords could be either 16 or 32 bytes long when encrypted, and security answers could be 16, 32, or 64 bytes when encrypted. I know what the block size is and how it works, but even using a block size of 32 bytes (the largest blocks ize available) I am still unable to control the length of the security answer (it could be 32 OR 64 bytes).

Is there a way to force my encrypted strings to be a particular length while still using AES and PCKS7 padding, without adding restrictions on the input?

Comment: It is quite predictable. See this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9044/18298) from CSE.

Comment: You are right, maybe predictable isn't the correct word. When I know the length of the input, the output length is predictable. But if I do not know the length of the input,  which is the case here, I cannot know the length of the output (other than it is a multiple of the block size).

Comment: If there is a max size that you accept from the user, then fill-zero padding is better for your cause.

Comment: @kelalaka Yeah, it seems like that will be my best option. Thanks for the input.

Comment: It was 10...0000 padding, so that you can remove from the end by looking the first 1.

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially asking for the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) to go away (which it won't).

I know you say you understand the block size, but it appears that you do not based on the sentence immediately following that claim.  The block size defines the length of the bit-string that is passed in to the algorithm and out of the algorithm.  That is it.  If you pass in 2.5 lots of 256-bits (which will be padded up to 3 blocks), then you're going to get 3 blocks of output.  Also, AES with a 256-bit block size isn't AES anymore, its Rijndael.

You can *predict* the output size for a given input under AES with PKCS7 padding, but you can't cap it to, say, 32 bytes.

If you weren't encrypting these fields, you'd still need to set a maximum field size in the database - the fact that they are encrypted doesn't change this.

Comment: I do understand the block size. What I was getting at is that if I have a block size of 256 bits, the only way to ensure the output length is to ensure the input is less than 256 bits. But in this case there are some inputs greater than 256 bits, making the output 512 bits.

Anyway, I appreciate your comment. It seems like what I'm trying to do is impossible (given the constraints I was hoping to satisfy), so I will have to find another solution. Thanks.

Comment: PKCS#7 works up to 256-byte block ciphers. That is the [difference](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9044/18298) between PKCS#5 and PKCS#7.